# Regarding the :nth-child and :nth-of-type selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Stumbled upon a problem that I can not figure out. An easy example of what I'm trying to do:

Highlight in RED every occurrence of the first 'span' under the class .row, except for the very FIRST occurrence, which should be highlighted in YELLOW.

```
.row span:nth-of-type(1) {
background: red;
}
```

Can this be accomplished by the *:nth-child* or *:nth-of-type* selectors? If not, how can this be done ***without resorting to inline styling***?

Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/z9mho7p5/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [:first-child](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/)

Comment: It depends on your definition of "first occurrence", as well as the structure of your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second rule, add `.row:first-child span` also

```
.row:first-child span, .row span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/z9mho7p5/2/

Comment: This is what worked for my situation. Added a bit more to in here [https://jsfiddle.net/z9mho7p5/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/z9mho7p5/4/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just simply

```
 .row span:first-child
 {
     background-color:red;
 }

 .row:first-child  span:first-child 
 {
      background-color:yellow ! important;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think `!important` is needed here. just add high specificity which I think you are doing already.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is depending on your code in JSfiddle, Use the `:not` (negation) to exclude the first paragraph.

```
.row:not(:first-child) span:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}

.row span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/z9mho7p5/3/)

[image: Output of :not(first-child)]

Comment: It wont make first child of first span into yellow

Comment: Based on the text requirement on JSfiddle, I have used this.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.row:nth-of-type(1) span { background-color: yellow; }`.

https://jsfiddle.net/z9mho7p5/1/